# BlockRSSParser Programmatic Issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

I am currently working on a company app in my quiet times (whenever I don't have a active project going on)

My main background is in WebDevelopment and some C and stuff anyway.

I thought I'd try my hand at iOS App Development.

Anyway so I am trying to load our company blog RSS feed into a tableview.

I set up some views and controllers (all Programmatically) the Tableview worked fine and the RSS Loading worked fine too using MWFeedParser.
The "problem" was that it didn't support ARC and all somehow it also felt like I was clogging the project with hundreds of Class Files.

So I opted to look for a RSSParser that had ARC Enabled and so I found BlockRSSParser.

I added it into the project but their sample app uses Interface Builder which I don't want to use (for numerous reasons) so in my code the app crashes on the TableView Delegates.
Specifically the "NumberOfRowsInSection" Method.

Now I know that the code I use to return the number is wrong, but that is where I am stuck.

In the Sample of the code they have a UITableViewController.
Where the DataSource is already Defined.
While I have a UIViewController and a UITableView whereas I need to set the delegate and the datasource itself.

So In their sample they use:

```
return [DataSource count];
```

Which indeed should return the number of FeedItems but whatever I enter it does not seem to work for me.
The App either crashes or just does not display a feed item.

The whole code can be found here:
[GitHub](https://github.com/Shuyinsama/RedactiePartners)

the file where the specific code exists is here:
[.m file](https://github.com/Shuyinsama/RedactiePartners/blob/master/RedactiePartners/RPHomeViewController.m)

I have no idea anymore! definitely could use some help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not passing the *feedItems to your NSArray *itemsToDisplay, hence no data is being populated. Here's a slight modification to your RSS parsing block.

```
// NEW RSS
NSURLRequest *req = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://redactiepartners.wordpress.com/feed/"]];
[RSSParser parseRSSFeedForRequest:req success:^(NSArray *feedItems) {
    [self setTitle:@"Blog"];
    [self.rssFeedView setDataSource:self];
    self.itemsToDisplay = feedItems;
    [self.rssFeedView reloadData];
} failure:^(NSError *error) {
    [self setTitle:@"Error"];
    NSLog(@"Error: %@",error);
}];
```

**EDIT** For the sake of clarity, the above code is from your RPHomeViewController.m

Comment: I must say... this looks like a stupid rookie mistake on my part and not even objective-c specific... the fact that I missed this makes me feel ashamed hahaha. Many thanks though!